# scanf() not taking multiple inputs

Tags: c, scanf

Hi I just started learning C programming in `gcc` compiler on my Debian system. Here is the code

```
main()
{
    fflush( stdin );
    int a,b;
    scanf("%d,%d",&a,&b);
    printf("%d,%d",a,b);
}
```

The `scanf` doesn't take input for the second variable. I press 2 and then return key and it displays

```
root@debian:/home/wis# ./test
2
2,0root@debian:/home/wis#
```

I have used space and tab key also. Please help me.

Comment: Please read some C books before asking beginners questions!

Comment: Remove `fflush( stdin );`. And `main()` → `int main(void)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined your `scanf` string as `"%d,%d"`, so the program expect an input like `1,2`.

If you give it only one digit and press Enter, it parses the first digit and leaves the second one untouched. It was assigned `0` on declaration, so that's what you are seeing when printing.

Your `printf` statement would benefit from an `"\n"` at the end, and your code snippet needs indentation. Please show your includes (`#include <stdio.h>`) next time, it makes it easier for us to compile and run the code.

Comment: "_It was assigned 0 on declaration_" No its not.